# Is it possible to dispatch S3 methods based on the class of an argument specified by its position only?

Tags: r, dispatch

Imagine we have the following S3 generic that we want to dispatch using the class of the first argument:

```
genfun <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("genfun", x)
```

Let's now consider a `numeric` method for this generic:

```
genfun.numeric <- function(x, y) {
  x[y]
}
```

The following call works just perfectly well:

```
genfun(1:5, 3)
```

Of note, it appears that the names of the arguments of the method do not need to match those of the generic. Indeed, if we define the `numeric` method this way:

```
genfun.numeric <- function(a, b) {
  a[b]
}
```

It also works:

```
genfun(1:5, 3)
```

However, the following call fails:

```
genfun(a = 1:5, b = 3)
```

whereas, if we return to the first definition of the method that match the arguments' names of the generic:

```
genfun.numeric <- function(x, y) {
  x[y]
}
```

a call with named arguments works just fine:

```
genfun(x = 1:5, y = 3)
```

or:

```
genfun(y = 3, x = 1:5)
```

Is there a way to make the method definition based on arguments `a` and `b` also work when called with named argument?

Comment: Why the tag `amazon-s3`?

Comment: Why do you need this? It's better practice to use the same parameter names as in the generic.

Comment: I didn't use the tag `amazon-s3` but only the tag `s3`.

Comment: @Roland:  the reason I'd like to do so is because I'd ultimately like to do dispatch on the second argument, that may happen to have different names in different methods. But I agree it may not be a good idea. It was just to check before I make the change.

Comment: "I'd ultimately like to do dispatch on the second argument" that's not possible with S3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Define the generic *without* arguments other than the dots argument.

```
genfun <- function(...) UseMethod("genfun")
```

Now both methods work with or without named arguments.

```
genfun.numeric <- function(x, y) {
  x[y]
}

genfun(1:5, 3)
#[1] 3
```

And the other one.

```
genfun.numeric <- function(a, b) {
  a[b]
}

genfun(1:5, 3)
#[1] 3

genfun(a = 1:5, b = 3)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: That's wonderful, thanks a lot. What if now I want to do the dispatch on the second argument instead of the first? Would it still be possible?

Comment: @choisy No, I don't think so. S3 methods dispatch on the first argument.

Comment: Dispatch on first argument by default, by you can choose to dispatch on another argument if you want. For that, you just have to define the generic this way: `genfun <- function(x, y, ...) UseMethod("genfun", y)`